# Powershell IP scanner

Tags: powershell

i have this powershell script to check for unused ip

```
$ipgroupes = "192.168.2"
$ipstart = 1
$ipend = 255

$ipstart..$ipend  | ForEach-Object{
    $ip = "$ipgroupes.0" -replace "0$",$_

If (-not(Resolve-DnsName -Name $ip -QuickTimeout -Type ANY -ErrorAction              
    SilentlyContinue) -And (!(Test-Connection $ip -count 1 -quiet)))

    {

        write-host "$ip is not used" -ForegroundColor Green


    }



}
```

the script is working fine but i've been asked to exclude the ip 80 to 149 from the search. I need help on how to get this done ?

Comment: You could do `1..79 + 150..255 | ForEach-Object {`, (but it's not as flexible as having an "exclude range").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this. to undo the exclude, you can set both exclude values to 0

```
$ipgroupes = '192.168.2'
$iprange = 1..255
$excluderange = 80..149

$iprange | Where-Object {$_ -notin $excluderange} | ForEach-Object {
    "$ipgroupes.$_"
}
```

*edit: updated with Matt's help

Comment: `Where-Object {$excludestart..$excludeend -notcontains $_}` seems simpler since we are already using the array operator. If not you should be using `-le` and `-ge`